# como obter o tempo da session em php

Tags: php

alguém sabe obter o tempo que falta para seciono expirar?

Estou criando ela assim:

```
session_start();
```

Queria exibir para o usuário o tempo que ele tem restante

Comment: vai ter que armazenar o relógio na hora da criação, e descontar do total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente utilizar o seguinte trecho:

```
$segundos=ini_get('session.gc_maxlifetime');
```

Comment: ok vlw, muito obrigado

Comment: isso dá o máximo, não o tempo de expiração da sessão atual.